# Businesslogic.xml and Cms.xml

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, umbraco

I am trying to set up an Umbraco3 site on my Visual Studio 2008. All I have managed so far is just create the solution and get the files imported. When I debug the solution I get an error saying "umbraco.Datalayer.dll" is missing. I see a reference to this dll in the businesslogic.xml file on my workstation. Is this a common file available to anyone that installs umbraco? And also, we have a live version of this site in Production. And the site does not have umbraco.Datalayer.dll either but still works fine. I have been asked to do some new development on the site and that is why I want to set up the project in Visual Studio. I am stuck now as the files I have in subversion might be mixed up and using production files wont be of much help because it does not have the business code at all. There is just the dll produced out of building the business layer in prod. Please suggest a way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult one, since Umbraco 3 has been superseded for quite some time. Even the official [release list](http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases) doesn't include Umbraco 3.

Provided your build doesn't include any bespoke coding, you could simply download the live version and work with that since you would know that it was at least the correct version.

If the project does have bespoke coding, then you are going to have to look through the subversion logs to see who made what changes and see if there was a point at which the trunk matches the live build and work from there.

What I would suggest is that you should convince your boss/client to upgrade as soon as possible, as it may be a cheaper option in the long run. Of course this depends on the complexity of the site.